# Can I make a header from a Static Library?

Tags: c, winapi, gcc, cygwin, winsock2

I have a library (ws2_32) and a header file (ws2tcpip.h) but for some reason there are functions in the library that are not in the header. Is there a way I can determine the method signatures so I can include them in the header myself?

```
asdf@fdsa ~$ strings /usr/lib/w32api/libws2_32.a | grep -i 'inet_*ntop'
_inet_ntop@16
__imp__inet_ntop@16
_InetNtopW@16
__imp__InetNtopW@16
inet_ntop                      <<< I need this one
_inet_ntop@16
__imp__inet_ntop@16
InetNtopW                      <<< or this one
_InetNtopW@16
__imp__InetNtopW@16
asdf@fdsa ~$ grep -i -B 4 -A 2 -R "ntop" /usr/include/w32api/ws2tcpip.h
asdf@fdsa ~$
```

This should be possible since the linker has to verify this, no?

Reference: [InetNtop and ws2tcpip.h under GCC / Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974328/inetntop-and-ws2tcpip-h-under-gcc-cygwin)

Comment: For C functions, the linker generally only checks that the function names match, not that they have the same type or calling conventions.  On some systems the linker will not even verify that the function you call is a function, it could be a chunk of data.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.  Not without disassembling the library and doing a lot of guesswork.  Consider it hopeless, in general.

However, functions like `InetNtopW` and `inet_ntop` are documented ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805843%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), so we know what the function signatures are.  Note that the functions are marked as requiring Vista, and indeed you can see in `WS2tcpip.h` they are surrounded by a guard:

```
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_VISTA)
```

So you will not get the prototypes unless you define the preprocessor macros for Vista support.

```
// Require Vista
#define WINVER 0x0600
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
```

Alternatively, you can use `WSAAddressToString`.  It is a similar function, but not exactly compatible.  The `WSAAddressToString` is available from Windows 2000.

**Footnote:** The `InetNtopW` and `inet_ntop` functions are basically the same thing, except the W version takes `wchar_t` and the `inet_ntop` takes `char`.  Many Windows functions are duplicated this way.

Comment: I do have the required #defines, but I can assure you the definition is not in the header (as per grep). I'm aware of the WSA* functions but I cannot use them in this case. Your link points to the MSDN for InetNtop, but if you notice that is not represented in the library file (as per strings)

Comment: @Huckle: `InetNtop` wouldn't show up in the library because it's not a function, it's a preprocessor macro that is defined to `InetNtopW` or `inet_ntop` depending on the value of the `UNICODE` macro.  Is there a reason you can't use the `WSA` functions?

Comment: The WSA functions all require a call to WSAStartup prior to use, yet the primary purpose of my program is not to work with sockets at all so I don't want to waste time/memory on initializing something when there is a once-off function that will do the same without the added overhead. I have no need to use this on anything earlier than Vista (as it will be used under *nix in 80% of the cases anyway). Could you post your copy of Ws2tcpip.h to pastebin so I can diff it?

Comment: @Huckle: The `inet_ntop` functions are also Windows Sockets functions, meaning the same restrictions apply.  It's not just based on whether the function starts with WSA.

Comment: From your link: "The InetNtop function does not require that the Windows Sockets DLL be loaded to perform IP address to string conversion"

Comment: Sorry, I don't have Cygwin installed.  It sounds like you have old / outdated headers, do you have the Windows SDK installed?

Comment: I'm installing it currently, the effort MS makes me go through to code for their OS...